# How to get an array of data from $_POST

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a form with multiple textboxes with the same names. I want to get the data from all the textboxes in my PHP code.

Here is my code.

```html
Email 1:<input name="email" type="text"/><br/>
Email 2:<input name="email" type="text"/><br/>
Email 3:<input name="email" type="text"/><br/>
```

```php
$email = $_POST['email'];
echo $email;
```

I wanted to have a result like this:

> email1@email.com, email2@email.com, email3@email.com

Instead I only get the text from the last textbox.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Using `[]` in the element name

```
Email 1:<input name="email[]" type="text"><br>
Email 2:<input name="email[]" type="text"><br>
Email 3:<input name="email[]" type="text"><br>
```

will return an array on the PHP end:

```
$email = $_POST['email'];
```

you can `implode()` that to get the result you want:

```
echo implode(", ", $email); // Will output email1@email.com, email2@email.com ...
```

Don't forget to sanitize these values before doing anything with them, e.g. serializing the array or inserting them into a database! Just because they're in an array doesn't mean they are safe.

Answer (score 10):

```
<input name="email[]" type="text">
<input name="email[]" type="text">
<input name="email[]" type="text">
<input name="email[]" type="text">
```

$_POST['email'] will be an array.

Answer (score 5):

Another example could be:

```
<input type="text" name="email[]" value="1">
<input type="text" name="email[]" value="2">
<input type="text" name="email[]" value="3">

<?php
     foreach($_REQUEST['email'] as $key => $value)
          echo "key $key is $value <br>";
```

will display

```
key 0 is 1
key 1 is 2
key 2 is 3
```