# Nested loops in php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I cant update the corresponding edited items. Only the first questions and answers are being updated. I cant get the result that I want. Im stuck on this for a day. Please help me.

Heres the scenario: I have a php file that contains the form and passes it to another php file. a checkbox that has the question id and textboxes that allows them to edit their questions from the database. Every question has its corresponding answers. Also, they can edit them. If they click update button all of the checked questions should be updated. but not all of them is updated. Literally only the first question is the only item that can be updated. Anyone knows whats wrong with my code??

heres a link for the screenshot http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/706/cetw.png/

Heres my code:

```
$selected = $_POST['selected'];///the checkbox
$question = $_POST['questiondesc'];


for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($selected); $i++)
{
    $sql = sprintf("UPDATE exam_questions SET question_description = '%s' WHERE question_id = '%s'", 
           mysql_real_escape_string($question[$i]), 
           mysql_real_escape_string($selected[$i]));
    mysql_query($sql)or die(mysql_error());

    $eren = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM exam_answers WHERE answer_question_set_id = '".$selected[$i]."'")or die(mysql_error());
    while($mikasa = mysql_fetch_array($eren)){}
    $count = mysql_num_rows($eren);

        $answer = $_POST['answerdesc'];
        $answerid = $_POST['ansid'];///answer id



           for($e = 0; $e<$count; $e++){

           $gomugomu = sprintf("UPDATE exam_answers SET answer_description = '%s' WHERE answer_id = '%s'",
           mysql_real_escape_string($answer[$e]), 
           mysql_real_escape_string($answerid[$e]));
           mysql_query($gomugomu)or die(mysql_error());
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a little confusing to understand without a printscreen of your page or something, but it sounds like you have a page that allows multiple checkboxes to be selected at the same time, yet you're only keeping the reference for a single checbox in your `$_POST`.

If that's the case, you should be sending the questions' ID's through an array. Please take a look at this accepted answer to see how that can be done: [PHP $_POST get data array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3148743/php-post-get-data-array)

Comment: I have done those to my html code. here is my screen shot http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/706/cetw.png/